Flutter Web Page Starts Zoomed In on Some Devices
Summary of the Problem:
I am working on a Flutter web project, and sometimes, on certain devices, the page loads with a zoomed-in view. This happens despite having the viewport meta tag set correctly. To fix the zoom issue, I have to interact with the page (e.g., scroll or resize), which then adjusts the page to the correct size. I have tried using innerHeight and outerHeight to debug, but nothing seems to work. Below is my index.html file and the related screenshots.
Expected Results:
I expect that the page loads correctly without any zoom issues on all devices.
Actual Results:
On some devices, the page initially loads zoomed in. Only after interacting with the page (scrolling or resizing) does the zoom issue get fixed.
What I've Tried:
I have tried:

Setting the viewport meta tag correctly
Using innerHeight and outerHeight for debugging

None of these attempts have resolved the issue.
Code:
Here is my index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />

  <meta flt-viewport="" name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

  <meta name="description" content="Personalize seu site e sua lista de presentes" />

  <meta name="author" content="Lejour" />

  <meta name="keywords"
    content="lista de presentes, lista de casamento, presentes em cotas, presentes virtuais, lista em dinheiro" />

  <!-- Facebook / Open Graph -->
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Lista de Presentes" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Lista de Presentes" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Personalize seu site e sua lista de presentes" />

  <meta property="og:image" content="tag-image.png" />
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="1024" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="1024" />

  <link rel="preload" href="flutter.js" as="script" />
  <link rel="preload" href="splash/splash.png" as="image" />
  <link rel="preload" href="main.dart.js" as="script" />

  <!-- <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/amalfi-coast.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/belgant-aesthetic.otf" as="font" type="font/otf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/expressway.otf" as="font" type="font/otf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/NewYork.otf" as="font" type="font/otf" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/spinwerad.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/Icon/Lejour.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Merriweather-Bold.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Merriweather-Regular.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- <link rel="preload" href="assets/animation/loading/loading.riv" as="fetch" type="application/octet-stream" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

  <link rel="preload" href="croppie.min.js" as="script">
  <link rel="preload" href="exif.js" as="script">
  <link rel="preload" href="https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js"
    as="script">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="icons/apple-icon-57x57.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icons/apple-icon-60x60.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icons/apple-icon-72x72.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="icons/apple-icon-76x76.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icons/apple-icon-114x114.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icons/apple-icon-120x120.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="icons/apple-icon-144x144.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icons/apple-icon-152x152.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icons/apple-icon-180x180.png" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="icons/android-icon-192x192.png" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="icons/favicon-96x96.png" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />

  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff" />
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />

  <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=6448763358" />

  <title>Site e Lista de presentes</title>

  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>

  <meta name="google-signin-client_id"
    content="139931905945-pprmr0m0seuk0m252a095k1jd0u9qal1.apps.googleusercontent.com" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.6.2/cropper.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.6.2/cropper.min.js" defer></script>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .loader {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 9999;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .loader>img {
      width: 150px;
      object-fit: contain;
    }

    .loader-container {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 25%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      width: 70%;
    }

    .loader-indicator {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 5px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-top: 36px;
    }

    .loader-indicator-progress {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      background-color: #e2645a;
      border-radius: 5px;
      transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<script>
  console.log("Starting Flutter web app.");
</script>

<body>
  <div class="loader">
    <img src="splash.png" alt="Splash loading" />

    <div class="loader-container">
      <div class="loader-indicator">
        <div class="loader-indicator-progress"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const interval = window.setInterval(() => {
      const indicator = document.getElementsByClassName("loader-indicator-progress");

      if (indicator.length > 0) {
        const progress = indicator[0].style.width || 0;

        if (progress === "100%") {
          window.clearInterval(interval);
          return;
        }

        const newProgress = parseInt(progress) + 15;

        indicator[0].style.width = `${newProgress}%`;

        if (newProgress >= 90) {
          window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }
    }, 1000);


    window.addEventListener("load", (ev) => {
      console.log("Loading main.dart.js.");
      console.time("main.dart.js download");

      if (!window._flutter) {
        window._flutter = {};
      }

      _flutter.buildConfig = {
        engineRevision: "edd8546116457bdf1c5bdfb13ecb9463d2bb5ed4",
        builds: [
          {
            compileTarget: "dart2js",
            renderer: "auto",
            mainJsPath: "main.dart.js",
          },
        ],
      };

      _flutter.loader.load({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: `{{flutter_service_worker_version}}`,
        },
        renderer: "html",
        onEntrypointLoaded: async (engineInitializer) => {
          const indicatorProgress = document.getElementsByClassName("loader-indicator-progress");

          if (indicatorProgress.length > 0) {
            indicatorProgress[0].style.width = `100%`;
          }

          console.log("main.dart.js loaded.");

          console.timeEnd("main.dart.js download");

          console.time('initializeEngine');

          const appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine();

          console.timeEnd('initializeEngine');

          console.time('runApp');

          appRunner.runApp();

          console.timeEnd('runApp');

          const indicator = document.getElementsByClassName("loader");

          if (indicator.length > 0) {
            indicator[0].remove();
          }
        },
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>

Additional Information:
Flutter version: 3.22.2
Browsers where issue occurs: Chrome - Android only
Devices where issue occurs: S22 Plus / Moto G9
How can I ensure that the Flutter web page loads correctly without any zoom issues on all devices?

I found a solution from this answer: Why is window.innerHeight incorrect until I tap? Chrome (Android)
i have to add the "interactive-widget=resizes-content" in meta viewport tag
And it works!
